# How to handle multiple JS events when they call the same function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to handle multiple JS events to call same function.. please look at the code..

My requirement is to check uniqueness of Client Code entered in a textbox.. So I'm using something like this:

My code:

```
<input type="text" 
onblur="function1(arg1,arg2)" 
onclick="function1(arg1,arg2)"
onfocus="function1(arg1,arg2)">
```

So, is there any other better way to rewrite this code?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, although I'd personally use `element.attachEventListener` to make it neater.

Comment: Ya.. it works fine for me.. but I am looking for an alternate as my piece code looks too messy.. I actually have a big JS function call..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plain JS:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var fld = document.getElementById("yourfieldid");
  fld.onblur=fld.onfocus=fld.onclick=function() {
    function1(arg1,arg2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use jquery you could do something like this example:

```
$('#foo').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('entered');
});
```

reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Depending on what your goal is though you might want to bind to a different event that more clearly identifies the need for your use-case. Perhaps onChange?

Comment: No.. I have no idea about jquery.. have not tried it either.. Just a way.. that can make this code clean..

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. "

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, mp! I've updated my answer to reference the more recent method you referenced.